# Identity parser

Tags: haskell, parser-combinators, trifecta

As an exercise¹, I've written a string parser that only uses [`char`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsers-0.12.9/docs/Text-Parser-Char.html#v:char) parsers and [Trifecta](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta):

```
import           Text.Trifecta
import           Control.Applicative            ( pure )

stringParserWithChar :: String -> Parser Char
stringParserWithChar stringToParse =
  foldr (\c otherParser -> otherParser >> char c) identityParser
    $ reverse stringToParse
  where identityParser = pure '?' -- ← This works but I think I can do better
```

The parser does its job just fine:

```
parseString (stringParserWithChar "123") mempty "1234"
-- Yields: Success '3'
```

Yet, I'm not happy with the specific `identityParser` to which I applied `foldr`. It seems hacky to have to choose an arbitrary character for `pure`.

My first intuition was to use `mempty` but [`Parser`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta-2/docs/Text-Trifecta-Parser.html) is not a monoid. It *is* an applicative but `empty` constitutes an unsuccessful parser².

What I'm looking for instead is a parser that works as a neutral element when combined with other parsers. It should successfully do nothing, i.e., not advance the cursor and let the next parser consume the character.

Is there an identity parser as described above in Trifecta or in another library? Or are parsers not meant to be used in a `fold`?

---

¹ The exercise is from the parser combinators chapter of the book [Haskell Programming from first principles](http://haskellbook.com/).

² As helpfully [pointed out by cole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57042184/identity-parser/57044340#57044340), `Parser` is an `Alternative` and thus a monoid. The `empty` function stems from `Alternative`, not `Parser`'s applicative instance.

Comment: What would you expect from `parseString (stringParserWithChar "") mempty "1234"` ? Should that fail? Raise a runtime error? Succeed with what result?

Comment: I personally would say it returns with a failure, saying it expected the empty string.

Comment: I see. Perhaps you should handle that case as a special case, and then handle non-empty strings with `foldr1` instead, avoiding the need for `identityParser`.

Comment: An aside: any time you see `foldr f n . reverse`, you can rewrite that to `foldl (flip f) n` with no change in meaning and likely a performance improvement. Any time you see `foldl f n . reverse`, you should almost certainly rewrite that to `foldr (flip f) n`, which may increase laziness and likely also improves performance. In this case, though, neither seems so sensible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you want this to parse a `String`? Right now, as you can tell from the function signature, it parses a `Char`, returning the last character. Just because you only have a `Char` parser doesn't mean you can't make a `String` parser.

I'm going to assume that you want to parse a string, in which case your base case is simple: your `identityParser` is just `pure ""`.

I think something like this should work (and it *should* be in the right order but might be reversed).

```hs
stringParserWithChar :: String -> Parser String
stringParserWithChar = traverse char
```

Unrolled, you get something like

```hs
stringParserWithChar' :: String -> Parser String
stringParserWithChar' "" = pure ""
stringParserWithChar' (c:cs) = liftA2 (:) (char c) (stringParserWithChar' cs)
-- the above with do notation, note that you can also just sequence the results of
-- 'char c' and 'stringParserWithChar' cs' and instead just return 'pure (c:cs)'
-- stringParserWithChar' (c:cs) = do
--   c'  <- char c
--   cs' <- stringParserWithChar' cs
--   pure (c':cs')
```

Let me know if they don't work since I can't test them right now…

## A digression on monoids

> My first intuition was to use mempty but Parser is not a monoid.

Ah, but that is not quite the case. [Parser](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/trifecta-2/docs/Text-Trifecta-Parser.html) is an [Alternative](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html#t:Alternative), which is a [Monoid](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Alt). But you don't really need to look at the `Alt` typeclass of `Data.Monoid` to understand this; `Alternative`'s typeclass definition looks just like a `Monoid`'s:

```hs
class Applicative f => Alternative f where
  empty :: f a
  (<|>) :: f a -> f a -> f a
  -- more definitions...
```

```hs
class Semigroup a => Monoid a where
  mempty  :: a
  mappend :: a -> a -> a
  -- more definitions...
```

Unfortunately, you want something that acts more like a product instead of an `Alt`, but that's what the default behavior of `Parser` does.

Answer (score 1):

Let's rewrite your fold+reverse into just a fold to clarify what's going on:

```
stringParserWithChar :: String -> Parser Char
stringParserWithChar =
  foldl (\otherParser c -> otherParser >> char c) identityParser
  where identityParser = pure '?'
```

Any time you see `foldl` used to build up something using its `Monad` instance, that's a bit suspicious[*]. It hints that you really want a *monadic* fold of some sort. Let's see here...

```
import Control.Monad

-- foldM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
attempt1 :: String -> Parser Char
attempt1 = foldM _f _acc
```

This is going to run into the same sort of trouble you saw before: what can you use for a starting value? So let's use a standard trick and start with `Maybe`:

```
-- (Control.Monad.<=<)
--   :: Monad m => (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> a -> m c
stringParserWithChar :: String -> Parser Char
stringParserWithChar =
  maybe empty pure <=< foldM _f _acc
```

Now we can start our fold off with `Nothing`, and immediately switch to `Just` and stay there. I'll let you fill in the blanks; GHC will helpfully show you their types.

[*] The main exception is when it's a "lazy monad" like `Reader`, lazy `Writer`, lazy `State`, etc. But parser monads are generally strict.